# Send formdata through JS file to the handler in vb.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, form-data, generic-handler

I have tried this code successfully in **`aspx`**  file. But when I'm trying the same code in separate **`JS`** file, I'm unable to find the **`context.Request.Form`** & **`context.Request.Files`** in generic handler.

Link for the code I've tried is - [Create Generic HTTPHandler in asp.net with multiple values using AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029636/create-generic-httphandler-in-asp-net-with-multiple-values-using-ajax-call)

Problems:
1> Is it possible to use same handler in multiple files?
2> Generic Handler is being called from the JS file, but why I'm not getting values in handler sent from JS file?